# Salesforce REST API SOQL get account for opportunies

Tags: salesforce, soql

I want to do a query for all my opportunities (or contacts or whatever) and then join in the account so I can get the name etc. I'm able to get it to work querying accounts and joining the opportunities, but not the other way around.

```
select Name, Id, (select Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName, Amount from Opportunities where ownerId = 'id') from Account
```

Is there a way to do the query on opportunities instead? I don't want to get all accounts and loop through to get the opportunity data. Should be a simple belongs to type relationship.

I've tried such queries as:

```
select Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName, Amount, (select Name, Id from Account) from Opportunity where ownerId = 'id'
```

But that gives me "Didn't understand relationship 'Account' in FROM part of query call."

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For child->parent relationships you just use a dotted path to the fields you want, e.g.

```
Select id, Amount, CloseDate, Account.Name from Opportunity
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that for custom objects (For example `Person__c`) the name changes to `__r` when you do the dot operator. That is, if you have a reference to a person from an account and you want the person's `Name` you'd have to do `Person__r.Name`